# Mysql add variable in select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have a query like this

```
SELECT a.id AS col1, b.id AS col2, b.title AS col3
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id=b.id
```

this query is working properly, now if i make a subquery and pass the value of col2, like this

```
SELECT a.id AS col1, b.id AS col2, b.title AS col3, (
    SELECT a.name
    FROM tbl1 a
    INNER JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id=b.id
    WHERE a.id= [value of col2]
)
FROM tbl1 a INNER JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id=b.id
```

how can i achived to pass the value of col2 in subquery? Thanks in advance

Comment: use this subquery in another join condition. You can copy paste it exactly like this with the parentheses, giving it an alias, in a join condition. You will have to adapt your recordsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use the [MySQL User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) in order to avoid multiple joins and keep the code "more readable"

```
SELECT a.id AS col1, @myBCol2Value := b.id AS col2, b.title AS col3, (
  SELECT a.name
  FROM tbl1 a
  INNER JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id = b.id
  WHERE a.id = @myBCol2Value
) AS name
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I just transform your query to do what you want, here is the result:

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS col1, 
    b.id AS col2, 
    b.title AS col3,
    t.name
FROM 
    tbl1 a 
        JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id = b.id
        JOIN (
            SELECT a.id, a.name 
            FROM tbl1 a 
                JOIN tbl2 b ON a.tbl2_id = b.id 
            ) t ON t.id = b.id;
```

But I'm pretty sure you can simplify it. It is not clear to me as to why you want to join it that way, but probably it is because the table names are not the real ones.